# camera settings scale 1:1

Tags: camera, scale

Have som problem with the camera settings (I guess) when I use 1:1 scale.. in viewport rendering it seems normal but when I render the picture many object have been under som strange sea-level and the square-room is lika a big inside, non high quality spher..

anybody knows?

[image: Rendered picture]
[image: Render viewport view]
[image: settings]

Comment: Add a new camera, adjust the camera and render it.

Comment: it IS a new camera there, and I can se little bit of the objekt in the scene..